# ${value} in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, string, formatting

I do have a very simple use case:

```
it('Formatting with ${}', () => {
   const value = 1
   const info = 'the result is: ${value}'

   assert.equal(info, 'the result is: 1')
})
```

But it doesn't work and I can't see why. It's using ES6 because arrow function works. I tried let instead of const, even var. Nothing works.

Can anybody help?

Best regards,
Torsten

Comment: Change the single quote to backticks for `info` variable.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use back-ticks (`` ` ``) instead of single quote (`'`) or double quote (`"`) to use string interpolation

```
it('Formatting with ${}', () => {
    const value = 1
    const info = `the result is: ${value}`

    assert.equal(info, 'the result is: 1')
})
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
`the result is: ${value}`
```

instead of `'the result is: ${value}'` .

This happens because in JavaScript there's a concept of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which let's user evaluate *embedded expressions*. You can read more about it in the link provided.

Comment: Haha! I had the same problem. How do you put backticks inside backticks? EDIT: You can use backticks by wrapping it in double backticks `` something ``

Comment: @ChiragRavindra also, there has to be some space b/w text & backtics otherwise it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'result is: ${value}'

Please use Backticks

```js
const test = 'hello!'


// Template Literal
console.log(`testing: ${test}`)
```

If you dont know where Is the Backtick is Mostly near the Esc button

Hopes this help